# Matlab ODE to solve 2DOF vibrational systems

Tags: matlab, ode, vibration

I'm currently learning Matlab's ODE-functions to solve simple vibration-problems.

For instance mx''+cx'+kx=F*sin(wt) can be solved using

```
function dx = fun(t,x)

m=0.02;     % Mass - kg
k=25.0;     % Stiffness - N/m
c=0.0125;   % System damping - Ns/m
f=10;       % Frequency
F=5;

dx= [x(2); (F*sin(2*pi*f*t)-c*x(2)-k*x(1))/m]
```

And then calling the ode45 function to get displacement and velocity

```
[t,x]=ode45(@fun,[0 10],[0.0;0.0])
```

My question, which I have not fully understood searching the web, is if it is possible to use ODE-function for a multiple degree of freedom system? For instance, if we have two masses, springs and dampers, which we excite att mass 1, we get the following equations:

m1*x1''+c1*x1'-c2*x2'+(k1+k2)*x1-k2*x2 = f1(t)

m2*x2''-c2*x1'+(c1+c2)*x2'-k2*x1+k2*x2 = 0

Here, the displacements x1 & x2 depend on each other, my question is how one should go about to solve these ODE's in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction that the inputs to the function solved by `ODE45` be scalar.  Just pass in an input matrix and expect out an output matrix.  For example here is a function that solves the position of a 6 bar mechanism.

```
function zdot = cp_solve(t,z)
%% Constants
g = -9.81;
L1 = .2;
m0 = 0;
I0 = 0;
m1 = 1;
I1 = (1/3) * m1 * L1^2;

%% Inputs
q = z(1:6);
qdot = z(7:12);

%% Mass Matrix
M = zeros(6,6);
M(1,1) = m0;
M(2,2) = m0;
M(3,3) = I0;
M(4,4) = m1;
M(5,5) = m1;
M(6,6) = I1;

%% Constraint Matrix
Phiq = zeros(5,6);
Phiq(1,1) = 1;
Phiq(2,2) = 1;
Phiq(3,3) = 1;
Phiq(4,1) = 1;
Phiq(4,4) = -1;
Phiq(4,6) = (-L1/2)*sin(q(6));
Phiq(5,2) = 1;
Phiq(5,5) = -1;
Phiq(5,6) = (L1/2)*cos(q(6));

%% Generalized Forces
Q = zeros(6,1);
Q(5) = m1 * g;

%% Right Side Vector
rs = zeros(5,1);
rs(4) = (L1/2) * cos(q(6)) * qdot(6)^2;
rs(5) = (L1/2) * sin(q(6)) * qdot(6)^2;

%% Coefficient Matrix
C = [M Phiq'; Phiq zeros(5,5)];
R = [Q; rs];
%% Solution

Sol = C \ R;

zdot = [qdot; Sol(1:6)];
end
```

The inputs are the positions and velocities of the members.  The outputs are the new positions and velocities.

You use it the same way you would any `ODE45` problem.  Setup the initial conditions, define a time and solve the problem.

```
%% Constants
L1 = .2;
C1 = L1/2;
theta1 = 30*pi/180;
theta_dot1 = 0;
tspan = 0:.001:2;

%% Initial Conditions
q = zeros(6,1);

q(6) = theta1;
q(4) = C1 * cos(q(6));
q(5) = C1 * sin(q(6));

qdot = zeros(6,1);
qdot(6) = theta_dot1;

z0 = [q; qdot];

%% Solve the problem

options = odeset('RelTol', 1.0e-9, 'AbsTol', 1.0e-6);
[Tout, Zout] = ode45(@cp_solve, tspan, z0, options);
```

In your case you have 2 equations and 2 unknowns.  Set the problem up as a matrix problem and solve it simultaneously in your function.  I would recommend the modal approach for your case.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I played around with your comments a bit, and I got it to work! I solved what I wanted to do basically by setting x(1)=x1, x(2)=x1', x(3)=x2, x(4)=x2', and then defining x(2) and x(4) from the equations (just like in my example, but with two unknowns. dx=[x(2);(TQ-ct2*x(2)-kt2*(x(1)-x(3)))/J1;...
    x(4);(ct2*x(4)-kt2*(x(3)-x(1)))/J2];
This is not the exact same as my example, but similar just beacuse I wanted to test it.
However, I'm not using matrices here, so I wonder if there is another way to you actually meant? Also, sorry for the bad formatting, don't know how to fix...